# Rmarkdown: how to import all the *.bib files in a directory for bibliography?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibliography

In Rmarkdown file, how to import all the *.bib files in a directory for bibliography?

I have the following file tree

```
./
./the_Rmd_file_in_question.Rmd
./includes/
./includes/x.bib
./includes/y.bib
...
```

The followings don't work.

```
bibliography: 
  - ./includes/*.bib
```

or

```
bibliography: 
   `r library(stringr); str_replace(list.files(path = './report/includes/', pattern = '^.+\\.bib$', full.names = TRUE), pattern = './\\w+/', replacement = './')`
```

Comment: You need to give us more information if you want an answer that works, specifically what your directory structure looks like containing the Rmd file and the bib files.

Comment: @user2554330 see the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but it's a little tricky.  What Pandoc wants to see in the `bibliography` field is something like

```
bibliography: ["file1.bib", "file2.bib"]
```

I can get that with this code:

```
bibliography: ["`r paste(c('file1.bib', 'file2.bib'), collapse='\",\"')`"]
```

Given your updated structure of the directory, I think this should work:

```
bibliography: ["`r paste(list.files(path = './includes', pattern = '^.+\\.bib$', full.names = TRUE), collapse='\",\"')`"]
```

The `list.files()` call will give you usable names, you don't need to modify it.

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: "File  not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99"

Comment: Your expression didn't produce an acceptable list of filenames.  Try entering them by hand first like in my first and second examples, until you find the format that Pandoc wants.

Comment: Updated version works!